# Trying to serve multiple image files from nodejs to browser IMG tags

Tags: javascript, node.js

There are about 10 files in a directory called "assets" which are required by by various img tags in the main layout on the browser.

10 separate requests are sent to get the separate tiny image files. 
(eventually i will optimise this to just send one request to load a single image sheet consisting of all images in one)

But its sometimes unable to load all of them, so the browser shows the spinning/loading icon for ages till it timesout or it loads them but they are a wrong order/match (img tag will display a wrong image) or it just doesnt load the image, its a different behaviour everytime i refresh the page

```
//first request gzips and loads the main layout, subsequent requests loads images

require('fs').readFile('assets/'+params.file, function(err, data) {
  if(err) throw err;
  if(params.file == 'layout.html') {
  require('zlib').gzip(data, function(err, buffer) {
    if(err) throw err;
    output(buffer, params);        
   });
  } else output(data, params);
});


function output(data, params){ 
  switch(params.file.substring(params.file.length-3)) {
    case 'tml': params.headers = {'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'};break;
    case 'ico': params.headers = {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'};break;
    case 'ttf': params.headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-font-ttf' }; break;
    case 'otf': params.headers = {'Content-Type':'font/opentype'};break;
    case 'png': params.headers = {'Content-Type':'image/png'};break;
    case 'gif': params.headers = {'Content-Type':'image/gif'};break;
    case 'peg':
    case 'jpg': params.headers = {'Content-Type':'image/jpeg'};break;
    default: params.headers = {};
  }
  params.headers['Set-Cookie'] =  '';       
  params.responseOutput(data, params);
}
```

this feels a little like those pesky "closure" problems, but there are no forloops here and each image request from the browser should not interfere with another (..and yet it is)

Comment: Your switch will never match `jpeg`, since you're only looking the last 3 characters. Could that be at least part of the problem?

Comment: crap how did i miss that!, corrected it but it doesnt solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that some requests sometimes serve the wrong file suggests that you do have a closure issue, most likely involving `params` getting changed before either the `readfile` or `gzip` callbacks execute. What's its scope and how do you construct it (another possibility is that `params` itself is properly scoped, but it contains references to something that isn't)?

Comment: damn, you nailed it, it was the params variable that was causing the issue, it was in a global scope outside the "createServer(function(req, res){..}", so was probably holding the data between requests, moved it inside the "createServer" function and problems gone thanks